How to evaluate python code in org-mode when only python3 is provided by the package manager?
Recently I started to use guix as my operating system.
I installed python3 for my user via guix install python3.
python itself is not available in the package repository, which I verified by running guix search python.
I want to get started with org-mode and evaluate python snippets (or probably later other code-snippets as well in org-mode).
This is what I have in my init.el:
(org-babel-do-load-languages
 'org-babel-load-languages
 '(
   (emacs-lisp . t)
   (python . t)))

I evaluate the buffer to make sure the changes apply.
So here my actual question:
When I press C-c C-c above the python script, which looks like this:
#+begin_src python :results output
  print("Hello, Seaman!")
#+end_src

I get prompted to evaluate this python expression. I write "yes" and this is what comes out.
/gnu/store/295aavfhzcn1vg9731zx9zw92msgby5a-bash-5.1.16/bin/bash: line 1: python: command not found
[ Babel evaluation exited with code 127 ]

Babel is not able to find python, because I have python3 installed. Changing python to python3 in my init.el didn't help, because it displays the following after evaluating the buffer in the echo area:
Cannot open load file: No such file or directory, ob-python3. Not sure what to do here. Any help is welcome, thanks!

(use-package ob-python
  :custom (org-babel-python-command "python3"))


#+begin_src emacs-lisp :exports results :results none
(use-package ob-python
  :custom (org-babel-python-command "python3"))
#+end_src

#+begin_src python :exports results :results output
import sys
print(sys.version)
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: 3.11.8 (main, Mar 26 2024, 12:26:07) [GCC 13.2.0]




Thanks for the answer. I currently can't find the package in the melpa repository. Where is ob-python located. Also: Why did you assume that I use use-package? It was indeed a good guess. But I never mentioned it, which I probably should have.

Note also that I installed ob-ipython, which introduced some conflicts with org-roam, as one can see here:https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/12375

ob-python is part of Org mode and is installed in the same place that all the Org mode libraries are installed. use-package has nothing to do with MELPA. All that you need to ensure is that your Emacs can find the ob-python library to load it: IOW, set your load-path variable correctly (if it is not already set up correctly).

BTW, you don't have to use use-package. Customizing org-babel-python-command  and setting it to "python3" in your init file should be enough.

@NickD Could you clarify how to do that? I'm not an advanced emacs user yet. So I did not install Orgmode, therefore I don't know where the Org libraries are installed. Where are those by default? How do you mean without use-package? Could you also provide the exact command? Thanks!
